# Need to create a log-prob chart in .NET

Tags: .net, math, statistics, charts, probability

I can create a chart with a logarithmic scale on one axis, but I need to have a probability scale on the other axis as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail before anybody can help.  Is this homework?  What's the nature of your data?  Are you using a particular graphing or charting package?  Have you tried anything at all, or are you looking for help getting started?

Comment: It's not homework. This was previously done on log-prob graph paper - the intent with the differing scales is to make a mostly straight line with all the scatter points. I've looked at numerous APIs for charting packages, and most can do log scale, but I've yet to find one that allows you to combine that with a probability scale. 

I'm not 100% tied to .NET - I know Java pretty well, and am willing to learn another language if necessary to get this done.

I'm leaning toward using .NET's built in charting and trying to build a custom scale currently.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out, using Flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/). It allows for custom axis transforms using JavaScript, so I basically fed Math.log/Math.exp to one scale, and the JavaScript equivalent of Excel's NORMSDIST and NORMSINV to the other scale. Works great.